# Get emails whenever a file is uploaded on s3 bucket using serverless

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses, serverless

i want to get emails whenever a file is uploaded to s3 bucket as described in the title above, i am using serverless, the issue is that the event that i have created on s3 gives me just notification on s3-aws console, and  don't know how to configure cloudwatch event on S3 to trigger lambda. So please if someone knows how to triggered events on S3 using cloudwatch i am all ears.
Here is my code:

```
import json
import boto3
import botocore
import logging
import sys
import os
import traceback


from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from pprint import pprint
from time import strftime, gmtime

email_from = '*****@******.com'
email_to = '******@******.com'
#email_cc = '********@gmail.com'
email_subject = 'new event on s3 '
email_body = 'a new file is uploaded'


#setup simple logging for INFO
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def sthree(event, context):
 """Send email whenever a file is uploaded to S3"""
body = {}
status_code = 200


try:
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    ses = boto3.client('ses')
    response = ses.send_email(Source = email_from,
                    Destination = {'ToAddresses': [email_to,],}, 
                        Message = {'Subject': {'Data': email_subject}, 'Body':{'Text' : {'Data': email_body}}}
         )

response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": json.dumps(body)
}

return response
```

and here is my serverless.yml file

```
service: aws-python # NOTE: update this with your service name

plugins:
  - serverless-external-s3-event

provider:   name: aws   
runtime: python2.7 
stage: dev  
region: us-east-1   
iamRoleStatements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
              - s3:*
              - "ses:SendEmail"
              - "ses:SendRawEmail"
              - "s3:PutBucketNotification"
          Resource: "*"

 functions:   sthree:
    handler: handler.sthree
    description: send mail whenever a file is uploaded on S3 
    events:
       - s3:
          bucket: cartegie-nirmine
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: uploads/
            - suffix: .jpg
      - cloudwatchEvent:
              description: 'CloudWatch Event triggered '
              event:
                  source:
                      - "aws.S3"
                  detail-type:
                      - "S3 event Notification"
              enabled : true
```

Comment: It looks like you have a lambda which is triggered by an upload event. This lambda is supposed to fire an email, right? Have you checked the logs for the lambda to see if there is an error? I suggest you log the event to make sure you are receiving it.

Comment: Unless you need the flexibility afforded by writing code, you could simply configure an S3 event to publish to an SNS topic and subscribe to that topic by email address.

Answer (score 12):

If your motto is just to receive email notification of operations on a S3 bucket, then you dont need lambda functions for that. For the use-case mentioned in the question, you can achieve that using SNS topic and S3 events. I will mention the steps to follow from console(through the same can be achieved via sdk or cli).

1) Create a `Topic` using SNS console.

2) Subscribe to the topic. Use `email` as the communications protocol and provide your ***email-id***.

3) You will get email requesting you to confirm your subscription to the topic. Confirm the subscription.

4) **IMPORTANT**: Replace the access policy of the topic with the below policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "sns-topic-arn",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:s3-bucket-name"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically you are giving permission for your *s3-bucket* to publish to the SNS topic.

Replace ***sns-topic-arn*** with your ARN of the topic you created above.
Replce ***s3-bucket-name*** with your bucket name, for which you want to receive notifications.

5) Go to S3 Console. Click on your S3 bucket and open the **Properties** tab.

6) Under ***Advanced settings***, Click on ***Events*** Card.

7) Click *Add Notifications* and enter values. A sample has been shown below.

[image]

Select the required s3-events to monitor and the SNS topic you created.

8) Click **Save**. Now you should start receiving notifications to your email.

Comment: thank you for your response, i want to do all this using serverless, this is why i post the question. I think the majority did not understand my issue.